# Replacing firebase.config.js in Production Environment using Webpack

Tags: firebase, webpack

I'm trying to replace my firebase.config.js file when I'm in the production environment using Webpack. Here's the Webpack configuration I'm using:

```
const resolve = require('path').resolve;

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /firebase.config.js$/,
                loader: 'file-replace-loader',
                options: {
                    condition: process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'prod',
                    replacement: resolve(__dirname, './firebase.config.prod.js'),
                    async: true,
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In my Firebase config files (firebase.config.js and firebase.config.prod.js), I added a console.log('using prod/qa') to differentiate between environments. However, even in the production environment, it still seems to be using the qa config file. Can someone help me understand why this is happening and how I can fix it?